# simple .net Maui app and the hot reload for physical android devce in VS keeps failing to initialize

Tags: maui, xamarin-forms-4

I have a simple Todo app that I am working on through a tutorial. I have been using the Windows Machine hot reload fine. But I added in some swipe controls so I wanted to test it in the android emulator. I have the newest version of VS and the android emulator but I receive the below exception

[image]

Comment: You can refer to the doc: [XAML Hot Reload for .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin#troubleshooting). BTW, does that error still appear if you create a new project?